# Post Request not Sent to Server

Tags: angular, forms, angular-httpclient

I'm trying to post data to my API which I extract from a form.

The problem is that it wont try to send the post request at all. Register.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RegisterService } from '../register.service';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators, FormArray, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { user } from '../user'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
  public myForm: FormGroup;
  public submitted: boolean;
  public events: any[] = [];

  constructor(private registerService: RegisterService, 
  private _fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = new FormGroup({
      username: new FormControl('', [<any>Validators.required, <any>Validators.minLength(5)]),
      email: new FormControl('', [<any>Validators.required, <any>Validators.minLength(5)]),
      org_number: new FormControl('', [<any>Validators.required, <any>Validators.minLength(5)]),
      password: new FormControl('', [<any>Validators.required, <any>Validators.minLength(8)])
    });
  }

  save(model: user, isValid: boolean){
    this.submitted = true;
    this.registerService.postUser(model)
    console.log(model, isValid)
  }
```

And the service that it's calling:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { user } from './user';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators'
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

const HttpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-type': 'application/json' })
};
const HttpOption2 = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' })
}
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RegisterService {

  private usersUrl= 'api/v1/accounts';

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,

  ) { }

  getUsers(): Observable<user[]> {
    return this.http.get<user[]>(this.usersUrl)
  }
  postUser(object): Observable<user[]>{
    console.log(object)
    console.log('Did it enter this?')
    return this.http.post<user[]>(this.usersUrl, user, HttpOptions)
  }
}
```

My code outputs the expected information: username:'username', email:'email' etc.

And I know it calls the function since it also outputs:'Did it enter this?'.

My API isn't receiving a post-request and I have no idea why. I've been searching for answers on the [official angular Httpclient](https://angular.io/guide/http) pages, as well as numerous Stack overflow posts, I've tried adding .subscribe but I get the error type subscription is not assignable to type observable user, if i add .map() I get that map does not exist on type observable user, and if i add .pipe() I get no error message, but still no Post-request.
Whereas if i add .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError('addHero', hero))
    );
I get type observable user is not assignable to type observable user. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to subscribe to the request to get invoked,

```
  this.registerService.postUser(model).subscribe(result => this.result =result);
```

make sure to declare a variable named result to assign the responded data,

```
result : any;
```

Comment: declare a variable named result

Comment: Alright, now I've "got result does not exist on type RegisterComponent", any ideas?

Comment: you need to declare a variable named result, or remove the variable just put console.log(result)

Comment: Yeah that fixed it, im getting a 400 error atm:  "JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"} if you'd like to take a stab at that, but you did solve my problem1

Comment: so now your api is getting called, the above error is something related to the result that you access. check result using console.log. mark if it helped

Comment: This will leak unless you unsubscribe or take the first response. `this.registerService.postUser(model).take(1).subscribe(result => this.result =result);`